# Autokey won't start

Tags: keyboard, productivity

I installed `autokey-gtk` application but it won't start. When I run it from terminal it will write a message:

```
Xlib.protocol.request.QueryExtension
```

but that's all. The application won't start.

Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: On my system, Ubuntu, I get the same message when I start if from the terminal... That message in itself is not an error, because it runs perfectly...  It shows up as an icon in my top Panel...  The first time I ran it, I too, wondered what was going on...

Comment: Do you know where can I find it if I don't have the top panel in my XFCE? I removed it and have only bottom panel.

Comment: I added the top panel but this doesn't help.

Comment: Which distro are you using?  .. Autokey's Project homepage (http://code.google.com/p/autokey/) says, `KDE and GTK versions available, making AutoKey integrate well into any desktop environment.` ... So it should(??) work with XFCE...

Comment: I downloaded xubuntu (XFCE), installed it in a vm (VirurualBox), installed `autokey` (*the transitional package which helps users transition to the autokey-gtk package)*... and `autokey` works fine, so it isn't anything to do with XFCE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

8 years leater, but hopefully still useful for someone. From https://askubuntu.com/a/304834:

> The first time you launch AutoKey, it will start the service in the
>   background (the notification icon hasn't been updated for unity, so
>   there's no visual indication). Once it's running, you can bring up the
>   configuration interface by running the launcher again

So, Ubuntu 19.04 I have to type autokey twice from terminal. From dash once is sufficient.

Perhaps also useful: if Autokey does not start at login but you still selected that option, look at https://github.com/autokey/autokey/issues/149

Answer (score 1):

On my system, Ubuntu, I get the same message when I start if from the terminal... That message in itself is not an error, because it runs perfectly... It shows up as an icon in my top Panel... The first time I ran it, I too, wondered what was going on

After the initial install, if nothing shows up in your main menu, you can start the Configuration GUI via:

```
        autokey -c
      or
        autokey --configure
```

Comment: I had only `autokey-gtk`. So I installed `autokey` now. I have only command `autokey-gtk -c` but this has the same effect.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of, is just to mention that when I installed `autokey`, three packages were installed: `autokey`, `autokey-gtk`, and `autokey-common`

Comment: Another thought, but it is only guesswork; you could try using `autokey-qt` instead... They both work on my system.. The QT version installs `autokey-qt autokey-common libqscintilla2-5 python-qscintilla2`

Comment: `autokey-qt` has the same problem.